# Horizontally align image that's bigger than its parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a responsive website and I want to horizontally center an image that is wider than the parent DIV. The image has the same height as its parent. The image's width is proportionate to the height so it could render properly. I'm not able to put the image the a background-image.

How can I center the image horizontally? Preferably using CSS even though using jQuery is fine also.

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>

.div {
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.div img {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: none;
    width: initial;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/9t59m1br/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way to center image is to use combination of position absolute and negative translateX:

```
.div img {
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: none;
    width: initial;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fa000nkw/

Answer (score -1):

See if any of these flex box properties help...

```
 justify-content: center;

 align-items: center;
```

Also try it with display:flex; or display:inline-flex; if required.

Yup, works like a charm...

```
.div {
   background: #AAA;
   height: 220px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display:flex;
}
.div img {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: initial;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```